# How to make `getfacl` result arranged in folder name and file name alphabetical order?

Tags: bash

My system is centos7.I want to compare ACL of folder between backup and existing.

I notice a problem:`getfacl` result is not alphabetical ordered,then it's hard to user `beyond compare` to compare.

The ideal alphabetical order is: folder list by folder name alphabetical order. files within folder list by file name alphabetical order. as below:

```
# file: a
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---

# file: a/a.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---

# file: a/b.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---

# file: b
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---

# file: b/a.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---

# file: b/b.txt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---
```

How to make `getfacl` result arranged in folder name and file name alphabetical order?